# Software testing and regression testing

Tags: testing

My company has taken maintenance of a Drupal website where there are some modules that have been specifically developed for this site.

I have to answer to a question that most software do: how can we do "software testing" and "regression testing" with Drupal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal 7 comes with a Testing module, and for Drupal 6 you can download http://drupal.org/project/simpletest.

It doesn't do anything automatically (how could it..) but it allows you to write automated tests that test the functionality of your custom modules.

I wrote a blog post about this a while ago: [Writing automated tests for Drupal 7](http://blog.worldempire.ch/story/writing-automated-tests-drupal-7). Even though the title says Drupal 7, most of it applies to Drupal 6 too. See [Simpletest documentation](http://drupal.org/simpletest) on drupal.org for more information.

Answer (score 3):

- Using tools like [Selenium](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http://seleniumhq.org/&rct=j&q=Selenium&ei=eF6ZTuDxCM-a-gblv8y7BQ&usg=AFQjCNHCelhj_BWssRX2H0HZCcPqhgBrRg&sig2=Nyo94DkAA13mGirYqYE9Wg&cad=rja), you can automate testing of the website. This is not Drupal a specific solution and can be used with any web stack.
- Drupal 6 and 7 have their own testing framework called [SimpleTest](http://drupal.org/simpletest) which can be used to perform functional testing and unit tests (with some caveats, because Drupal itself isn't suited for unit testing). This solution is tied to Drupal and requires a good understanding if Drupal as a developpement platform.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but I think your question is a little too broad to answer.

It sounds like you need to maintain a site, and the site has custom modules that it uses.

It also sounds like maybe you are interested in knowing how to go about testing new changes you intend to make for the site.

If all of this is true then I think you need to learn Drupal first.

This page should get you started: http://drupal.org/documentation/develop

You may also want to look at the Devel module: http://drupal.org/project/devel

If you have a little more specific details let us know so we can help you out.

Comment: Thank you I check this as good, because it summarize what I've asked for and a solution (which may not be the best but it seems there's no automatic tool to insure that some things still behave the way we want). Thank you very much indeed!